# Converting advanced search strings into associative array

Tags: php, regex, search

How do I consume advanced search terms and convert them in to an associative array.

Example 1:

```
$term = 'blue birds country:england'
```

Would be converted to something like:

```
[
    'country' => 'england'
    'other' => 'blue blirds'
]
```

Example 2:

```
$term = 'country:"united kingdom" blue birds month:January'
```

Would be converted to something like:

```
[
    'country' => 'united kingdom',
    'month' => 'January',
    'other' => 'blue blirds'
]
```

I have attempted to do this with preg_match but I am struggling with differenciating between single words in a a group (e.g. `group:word`) and multiple words in a group inside double quotes (e.g. `group:"word1 word2 word3"`).

Comment: is there a term that have spaces in their values? for example other=blue red birds xxx yyy

Comment: @AliGhalambaz yes, in that case I would expect the words to be contained in double quotes. e.g. country:"united kingdom" would then become ['country'=>'united kingdom']

Comment: You can use a regex such as `[\w]+:([\w]+|"[\w\s]+")` to pull out the key-value pairs. You might be better splitting the string using a regex that can detect the spaces that are not inside quotes and then processing each item separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `preg_match_all()` this splits the string into various components.

`(\w*?):(".*?"|\w*)|(\w+)` splits it into `name:"values"/value` and `value` parts.  These are then assembled back into an output with the appropriate parts (checking which part of the regex has matched)

```
$term = 'blue birds country:england';
$term = 'country:"united kingdom" blue birds month:January';
print_r(splitTerms($term));

function splitTerms ( string $input )   {
    $matches = [];
    preg_match_all('/(\w*?):(".*?"|\w*)|(\w+)/', $input, $matches);
    $out = [];
    $other = [];
    // Loop over first matching group - (\w*?)
    foreach ( $matches[1] as $key => $name )    {
        if ( !empty($name) )    {
            // If name is present - add in 2nd matching group value  - (".*?"|\w*) (without quotes)
            $out[$name] = trim($matches[2][$key],'"');
        }
        else    {
            // Otherwise use 3rd matching group - (\w+)
            $other[] = $matches[3][$key];
        }
    }

    if ( count($other) > 0 )    {
        $out['other'] = implode(" ", $other);
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Which gives...
Array

```
(
    [country] => united kingdom
    [month] => January
    [other] => blue birds
)
```